# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable for append()

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class List:
    list = []
    def append(self, append):
        print(append())
        #self.append = append

    def displayList(self, displayList):
        print(displayList())
        #print(self.append)



def main():
    list = List()
    list.append('abc')
    list.append('def')
    list.append('ghi')
    list.displayList()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is your input and output? The issue is in `def append(self, append):
        print(append())` , are you sure you want to call the parameter `append` as a function ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 1):

You have a method `append` (referenced with `self.append`), with a parameter `append`, then the method calls the passed argument `append`. But in your `main` you call the object's `append` method and send it a string. Remember that in that method you're calling the passed argument. Since that argument is a string, you can't call it.

The other method in your class, `displayList`, does the exact same thing as `append`, only you're calling it with no argument at all, which will also generate an error.

Don't attempt to fix these issues by prepending `self` (`print(self.append())` or `print(self.displayList(0))`), as that will simply exceed the maximum recursion depth.

Your `List` class's `list` is also a class variable, not an instance variable. That will probably result in more problems later on.

I recommend taking a step back and thinking again about what you're trying to do and why. If you're creating this class for fun/education, there are probably [better ways to learn](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial). If you're doing it as part of a practical program (i.e., using it as a solution to a particular challenge), you may have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Guess what? It is because string object is not callable